# React Native sharing base64 image is not working

Tags: android, react-native, sharing

I am developing on android. My react-native version is **0.42**. I'm using [react-native-share](https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share) package for sharing screen view. The data I want to share is being converted to base64.

```
...
const uri = "data:image/jpeg;base64,...";

Share.open({
  title: "Title",
  message: "Message",
  url: uri,
  subject: "Mail subject"
})
...
```

This process was working properly on whatsapp, facebook and email before.
However, now, when I tried on whatsapp the response is *'Sharing failed. Please try again'*, on facebook I'm getting an empty text area without sharing options and on email I'm getting the text typed options except for the image.

Do you have any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Can't find anything on the code that clashes with *react-native-share* API, but have you checked using: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share.html

Comment: Before I had this situation I didn't. After that I tried but I couldn't share the image. url feature is just for ios in this module.

Comment: _targetSdkVersion_ of the project that I am working on has been 23. With version 23 system requires **Overlay permission** and it may interfere to use of the other applications. When I changed the sdkVersion to 22 in _android/app/buld.gradle_ and _android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml_ sharing worked normally again.

Answer (score 2):

I am using `react-native-share` but using the `shareSingle` option like this:

```
Share.shareSingle({
  message:'I just added a new outfit to my album.',
  url:Constants.image64, //base64 image
  social: "whatsapp"
});
```

It works great on both the platforms. You can try it if it suffice your needs.

Comment: Thank you but I need to share on any application that proper for sharing. However I tried _shareSingle_ for _whatsapp_ and I got the same response.

Comment: weird enough share.open does not work(file formate is not supported) but share.shareSingle works, how come?